# Is there a flying-rats / hidden packages equivalent in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Former GTA titles always featured some kind of collectable placed at various often hard to reach or somewhat special places throughout the map.

It was flying rats (= pigeons) in GTA 4, horseshoes/oysters in San Andreas, hidden packages in Vice City and GTA 3.

I haven't found or heard of any of those things in GTA V.
So is there some kind of collectable, or have they broken with tradition?

Comment: most open map free roaming games have such collectables, they are easy to insert and good trophy material

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the [checklist](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/career/checklist) available on Social Club, there appear to be 2 collectible missions listed under Misc. There are also 2 others not listed specifically on there, which makes 4 total.

1. Collect 50 spaceship parts. This will also net you the From Beyond the Stars achievement/trophy. To start this quest, you need to be Franklin, and start the mission "Far Out". Some guides for this mission can be [found here](http://www.trueachievements.com/a179399/from-beyond-the-stars-achievement.htm?showguides=1).
2. Collect 50 Letter scraps, which are available from the beginning of the game without starting any specific mission.
3. Collect 30 barrels of nuclear waste, which can be done after buying the Sonar Collections Dock for $250,000, and using the submarine.
4. Collect 30 submarine parts for Abigail, which is a side mission which starts on the Sonar Collections Dock (unsure if buying the property triggers this, or not).

Comment: Any information on if they are available from the start or if they require a start off mission?

Comment: @Chaos_99 Added the information I found on the 50 spaceship parts. Unsure about the Letter Scraps at the moment.

Comment: The letter scraps are available from the beginning, yes.

Comment: Also nuclear wastes & submarine parts which are not covered in Social Club checklist map.

Comment: There are also Hidden Packages (12).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are hidden packages.  I have found a few underwater in crashed planes and I'm sure there are a lot on land.  There's apparently one near a military base with bodies around.  Also, if you go into the water off the coast just north of the military base and find the plane wreck, the hidden package gives you 12,500 dollars.  Switch to another character and back, and the package is there again.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that there are over 180 collectible items: waste barrels, stunt jumps, space ship parts, letter scraps, and strange missions.

However, I'm not sure if they are the equivalent of the 200 flying rats from GTAIV. I really would like to know though!

http://www.gamefront.com/gta-5-all-collectible-locations-map-graphic/

Answer (score 0):

I (with the help of a few others) created a map on which you can view all collectables/packages etc. There are 45+ categories of items.

http://gta-5-map.com

Many of the categories have user-added content, which we moderate, but sometimes things slip through the cracks, and a location or two might be off by a few pixels.

The collectables and packages are all 'locked' though, so they should be 100% accurate.

If you sign in you can mark the ones you've already found and keep track of your progress!

Answer (score 0):

TPI industries state that if you find anything to bring it them. This is online, and there doesn't seem to be anything to find that you can take to them.

Answer (score -1):

There are space ship parts scattered around the map; a total of 50 pieces.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [gaming.se](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)! Thank you for your answer; however, please consider elaborating a bit as right not it's not terribly informative.